# Flask-migrate : How do I manage db of other installed modules

Tags: flask-migrate

I in the process of setting up Flask-migrate on an existing project. My project also uses Taskflow (`https://github.com/openstack/taskflow`) module.

Taskflow sets up its own tables. All this while I have been pointing taskflow to use the same db as the app and it creates its own 3 tables. Now with migrations enabled, I am getting this error

Can't locate revision identified by '397d0bf4d081'

[This is happening when I do upgrade of the taskflow backend connection - if that is of any significance]

I am not clear as to how migrations should be setup to manage tables of the packages/modules that are installed in the project.

As I was writing this question, I got the idea to point the module to itw own db.

I tried this and it works. The question boils down to what is the right approach - Whether DB requirements of installed modules should be managed by pointing it to separate db (appears like the right thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that taskflow uses Alembic to track its own database migrations, so your Alembic history (through Flask-Migrate) conflicts with that of Taskflow.

You have two options:

- the easiest is to use separate databases, as you have done.
- if you want to use the same database, then you have to do two things: first, use the [include_object](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure.params.include_object) option of Alembic in your project to configure your migrations to ignore the tables maintained by Taskflow, and second, configure the Alembic version table name to something different than the `alembic_version` default, which I assume Taskflow uses.

Comment: I will start with (1) but would also explore the inclide_object option.. thanks!